# Trying to install Eclipse or Codeblock

Tags: software-center, c++

I am new to using Ubuntu, and so in need of some help getting my development box up and running. I am trying to develop C++ code, but when I try to install CodeBlock IDE or Eclipse indigo, I run into some wall.

When I attempt to use Ubuntu Software to install Eclipse Indigo, I get an error about my internet connection "Failed to download Package File, Check your internet connection"(I use wireless and have no problems using the internet). When I try to install Codeblock, I get the same error. Is there some configuration issue I have not handled here? I am running Ubuntu on VMWare.  Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` and then downloading the software from the software center.

Comment: Like I said I am new to Ubuntu. How exactly would I run this command please?

Comment: Press `Ctrl+Alt+T` that will open a terminal. There copy & paste the code

Comment: Thanks. I did that, and it is running. What exactly would the above do?

Comment: Posted the explanation as an answer, so that you can mark it as the correct answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and type `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

`sudo apt-get update` refreshes your sources, basically it refreshes the sources from where the packages are going to be downloaded from and looks for new updates and so on.

`sudo apt-get upgrade` will download updates, if there any.